# Populating Array Data from Data Layer into GTM

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a Data Layer that is giving me information like this from Drupal

```
dataLayer = [{
            "entityType":"node",
            "entityBundle":"article",
            "entityTaxonomy":
                {"funnel_path":{"2":"Find a Park"},
                "byline":{"4":"Name1","5":"Name2"}},"drupalLanguage":"en",
                "userUid":"1"}
        ];
    </script>
```

I can easily use GTM's Data Layer variable to pull in entityBundle. How do I set it to pull in the information in byline? I tried `entityTaxonomy.byline`, but that give me an array. I can set to do entityTaxonomy.byline.4 to get Name1, but that would be silly since the editors would be regularly adding things.

I am planning to add the byline, ultimately, into Custom Dimension 2 in Google Analytics.

I am looking to have the data that goes to Custom Dimension 2 to be `Name1, Name2` . Sometimes this will be just one value. Sometimes it can be up to 20 values.

What do I need to do in GTM to get it to register that information?

Answer (score 0):

`entityTaxonomy.byline` actually gives you an object. You would need to do a bit of processing to get an array that you can join into a string. One possible way would be

```
temp = [];
Object.keys(test.entityTaxonomy.byline).map(function(key, index) {
    temp.push(test.entityTaxonomy.byline[key]);
});
bylines = temp.join(",")
```

(I'm sure that could be done much more concise). In GTM you would need to create a variable that contains the objects with the bylines, then you could do the processing in a custom javascript variable (which is by definition an anonymous function with a return value)

```
function() {
    var byLineObject = {{bylines}} // created as datalayer var beforehand
    temp = [];
    Object.keys(byLineObject).map(function(key, index) {
        temp.push(byLineObject[key]);
    });
    return temp.join(",")
}
```

Comment: Something is not working for me on this. I'm sorry. Here is what I did ...
# I created a variable named "Data Layer - Services" . I put in the Data Layer Variable name "services"  
# I created a custom Javascript named {{JS - Services}} and used the code above and put in {{services}} where the code love had {{bylines}}
# I updated my overall GA UA tag to add {{JS-Services as my Custom Dimensions Index 2 ... What am I missing?